How can I solve flet problems compiling?
I am having the following issue: I am developing an application with Flet, where it is essentially a checklist, and at the end, it generates a PDF file. I have tried various ways to make it work when compiling to APK, and currently, I am encountering this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 43, in <module>
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 229, in run_module
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\T-GAMER\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempde6426c2\main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\T-GAMER\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempde6426c2\__pypackages__\jnius\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jnius.jnius'

In the requirements.txt file, I have the following:
cython
flet
fpdf
requests
pyjnius
auto-py-to-exe

And in my code scope, the following imports are present:
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from fpdf import FPDF
import flet as ft
import webbrowser
import os
from jnius import autoclass

How can I resolve this error?
different ways to fix it, but I allways have the same problem when I convert to apk.
